# No such device or address

Tags: devices, scp

What does it mean if I get this message during `scp` ?

```
scp: /dev/fd/3/fd/3/fd/3/fd/3/fd/3/fd/3/fd/3/fd/3/fd/3/fd/3/fd/3/fd/3/fd/5/31/rd/c6d16: No such device or address
```

What I'm doing is

```
scp -r root@192.168.x.xx:/* .
```

Comment: You don't need the *

Comment: `scp` is not the right tool to duplicate a remote filesystem, especially a live filesystem with mount points like `/proc`, `/sys`, etc. `scp` follows symbolic links (i.e. they will not be preserved during the copy) and thus may be caught in symlink loops like this. Use `tar` through `ssh` for such a duplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process that is doing the recursion at the remote end is running as the superuser, and has recursed into `/dev/fd`.  Several of its open file descriptors are for directories that it is in the process of reading as part of the recursion.  Since they look like subdirectories as it traverses `/dev/fd` it is recursing them again.

It is even possible to determine what open file descriptors are open to what directories:

- file descriptor #3 is open to `/`
- file descriptor #5 is open to `/dev/fd`
- file descriptor #31 is open to `/dev`

It has reached, via a long and circuitous route, a point where it is trying to open and copy `/dev/rd/c6d16`, which does not correspond with a physical device.

Always be careful of commands, especially those run with superuser privileges, that will end up trying to naïvely open and copy all files in `/dev`, `/device`, `/proc`, `/sys`, and so forth.  This has been unwise since the days that `/dev` was full of tape devices (sometimes with auto-rewind/auto-retension) and terminal devices that would block an open call until carrier was detected.

Ensure that if you *really* want to copy `/dev`, which most likely *you do not* given that on modern operating systems its contents are determined dynamically at runtime, you use a command that copies special device files, FIFOs, sockets, and symbolic links as themselves, rather than naïvely attempting to open and read them as if they were regular files.  (Or that `open()` them and then `fstat()` to determine whether they are special devices, which will fail on device files that yield errors on `open()`.)